# aws VPC Endpoint が開放する必要があるポートは何ですか?

Tags: aws

VPC 上の lambda から KMS を利用するために、 KMS VPC Endpoint を、 次のページを参考に作成していました。 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-vpc-endpoint.html

Endpoint 自身も VPC 上のコンポーネントになるので、セキュリティグループを設定する必要がある様子です。セキュリティグループなので、 inbound 制限をメインで指定することになりますが、 endpoint がいいったいどういうものかよく分かっていないので、何のポートを開放すればいいのか、あまり明白ではないな、と思っています。

#### 質問

- VPC Endpoint が開放する必要があるポートは何ですか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS のリージョンとエンドポイント](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/general/latest/gr/rande.html#kms_region) によると KMS は https らしいので VPC Endpoint にも https を許可すればいい気がします。